# Display image image in JSP when Image data in Oracle database

Tags: jsp

I am try to access image data from oracle data base and display image on jsp. Write following code.

```
<%
try
{
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from PICTABLE where ID=200");
    if(rs.next())
    {
        Blob b1=rs.getBlob("PIC");
        byte x[]=b1.getBytes(1, (int)b1.length());
        OutputStream o=response.getOutputStream();
        o.write(x);
        o.close();
    }
    System.out.println("Done");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

When run this code and use IE browser then display image got error

```
[java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
```

When used chrome browser then image data not convert in image format and above mansion error is occurs. How to solve this problem for every browser.

Answer (score 0):

Did you call getWriter() somwhere on this page previously?
From the docs:

> Either this method or getWriter() may be called to write the body, not both.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream()

Answer (score 0):

Hope this could help

I recommend using String if it is stored as an image name in oracle database
While displaying we need to append the string to the location

```
<%
try
{
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from PICTABLE where ID=200");
    if(rs.next())
    {
        String b1=rs.getString("PIC");
        byte x[]=b1.getBytes(1, (int)b1.length());
        OutputStream o=response.getOutputStream();
        o.write(x);
        o.close();
    }
    System.out.println("Done");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
%>
<img src="foldername/<%=b1%>"   style="height:200px;"/>
```